# Rails where() and timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone, rails-activerecord

I am attempting to find 'entries' create today (in my current timezone) using the following:

```
Entry.where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?) AND email = ?", Time.now, email)
```

`Time.now` is giving me the time in the current zone, but the query seems like it is searching against the UTC time of each entry's created_at column.

Any ideas how I can find entries created today in the server's timezone?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're losing track of the timezone information as soon as you call the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function in your SQL. There are two things to keep in mind:

1. Everything inside the database will be in UTC and *everything* includes the result of `DATE()`.
2. A single date (i.e. day) in your local time zone can easily cross two dates in UTC so you need to look at the entire timestamp (on **both** sides) rather than just the (UTC) date components.

Something like this should work:

```
now = Time.now
Entry.where('created_at between :start and :end and email = :email',
    :start => now.beginning_of_day,
    :end   => now.end_of_day,
    :email => email
)
```

The times should be converted to UTC automatically. You might want to handle the upper bound a little differently; using `end_of_day` gives you `23:59:59` so there is a little room for something to slip through that you want to capture. You can get around that problem using an explicit half-open interval (rather than the closed interval that SQL's `between` uses) like this:

```
now = Time.now
Entry.where('created_at >= :start and created_at < :end and email = :email',
    :start => now.beginning_of_day,
    :end   => now.tomorrow.beginning_of_day,
    :email => email
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Time.now.utc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-gmtime)?

Comment: I thought of that, but it would then return entries based upon the 24 hour span of a day in UTC, not locally. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Time.zone.now`. That will use an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object that will be automatically converted to UTC when used in your database search.

Comment: That seems to have the same effect as using Time.now and Time.now.utc. It does look like the query is being built with UTC time, but that gives me entries within a day over in England, not where I am locally.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get timezone then timezone offset. 
For example current_time_zone is

> America/Los_Angeles

Time zone offset find :

```
 Time.now.in_time_zone(current_time_zone).utc_offset / 3600) * -1
```

> 7

In contoller :

```
 start_date_format = DateTime.strptime(@start_date, date_format)
 start_date_format_with_hour = 
 DateTime.strptime((start_date_format.to_i + timezone_offset*60*60).to_s,'%s').strftime(date_format)

 end_date_format = DateTime.strptime(@end_date, date_format)
 end_date_format_with_hour = DateTime.strptime((end_date_format.to_i + timezone_offset*60*60).to_s,'%s').strftime(date_format)

 @filters_date = "invoices.created_at >= ? AND invoices.created_at < ?", start_date_format_with_hour, end_date_format_with_hour
```